# same cookie notice reappears on subdomain despite it was accepted

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, cookies, vuejs3

I'm encountering an issue where, despite accepting cookies on the primary localhost, the cookie notification persists when I move to a subdomain such as requester.localhost. Same with if I accept cookies on a subdomain, the notification shouldn't show up again on the primary localhost (without a subdomain), yet it does.

Here is the script:

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      snackbar: true,
      timeout: -1,
    };
  },
  computed: {
    cookieAgreement() {
      return this.$cookies.get("cookie_agreement") === "1";
    },
  },
  created() {
    if (this.cookieAgreement) {
      this.snackbar = false;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    acceptCookies() {
      this.$cookies.set("cookie_agreement", "1", {
        path: "/",               // Set the path to root to make it accessible across the entire domain
        domain: ".localhost" // Set the domain to make it accessible across subdomains
      });
      this.snackbar = false;
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: The cookies are not treated the same way on localhost as that of a proper domain, especially when dealing with subdomains.

Comment: The thing is I uploaded the built to server to test it on real proper domain with subdomains, but same problem persists

Comment: For some reason dot (.) is not there before domain name even though I declared it in the code, I checked the cookie on chrome application cookie section

Answer (score 0):

Use `domain: "localhost"` instead of `domain: ".localhost"`

The leading dot is typically used to make cookies accessible for all subdomains of a specific domain `(e.g., .example.com)`, but for a local environment like **localhost**, you should remove the dot.

Comment: It's not what I wanted...

Answer (score 0):

So in general practice you should avoid using the literal string ".localhost". Instead, you should use the actual domain name without any leading dots for development environments. Since using ".localhost" might cause issues in some browsers, as they treat domains with a leading dot differently.
So for example you can do something like this

```
this.$cookies.set("cookie_agreement", "1", {
  path: "/",
  domain: "localhost"
});
```

Comment: Yes I know, I was just testing it on my local machine. I'm using dot so it would work across subdomains as well. When I put my actual domain name the dot disappears (but it should be there)